# URL Redirect Mod_rewrite with htaccess in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created some custom menus using functions.php in WordPress and I was hoping to use the htaccess to redirect those URLs to something friendly. For instance, one of the custom menus I have look like this for the menu: http://www.website.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers

How can I re-write it to be more like this:

http://www.website.com/wp-admin/for-buyers/

Also, My custom sub-menu look like this:

http://www.website.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=marketing_materials

I want it to be more like this:

http://www.website.com/wp-admin/for-buyers/marketing-materials/

Answer (score 1):

This has not been tested, the best is to modify vhosts, but you can use perdir .htaccess:

in /.htaccess, we can add this:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/for-buyers/$ /wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers [L]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/for-buyers/marketing-materials/$ /wp-admin/admin.php?page=marketing_materials [L]
```

This ruleset does this:

1. http://www.website.com/wp-admin/for-buyers/ => /wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers
2. http://www.website.com/wp-admin/for-buyers/marketing-materials/ => /wp-admin/admin.php?page=marketing_materials

Or in /wp-admin/.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^for-buyers/$ /wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers [L]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^for-buyers/marketing-materials/$ /wp-admin/admin.php?page=marketing_materials [L]
```

Comment: Should I add the above lines to my theme directory or create a new .htaccess and insert it inside my /wp-admin/ folder? It's not picking the rewrite for some reasons

Comment: It's better done in your root directory /, parent dir of wp-admin. IE, DOCUMENT_ROOT directory in your apache server.

Comment: I have tried the followings and it still not working: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/for-buyers/$ /wp-admin/admin.php?page=for_buyers [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress`